# No JNI_OnLoad found skipping init > Application shutdown

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

Folks,

I am working on an android application where I need a third party .so library. I built
this third party library (with ndk-build) as per their instructions and was then looking
to include this .so in to my Android project.

Therefore I followed the steps described in docs/PREBUILTS.html and successfully  build the
new .so in the jni/prebuilt directory. Now I tried leveraging the .so facilities by using it in a simple test android app. So what i do is :

```
static {
  Log.i("load so > ","load so");
  System.loadLibrary("xyz");
   }
/* The native functions */
private static native int openFile(String filename);

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    try{
        String path =  getPathForDownloadDirectoryFile();
        Log.i("file path> ", path);
        int num= openFile(path);
    }catch(Exception e){
        Log.e(">", "could not open the file");
    }
}
```

Now when I run my app I get a debug message saying :
No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/data/com.example.myfirstapp/lib/xyz.so 0x411e6738, skipping init
and then  the application shuts down.

For More Info, Here is the error log :

```
No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/data/com.example.mysecondapp/lib/xyz.so 0x411e67a0,   skipping init
W/dalvikvm(  570): No implementation found for native    Lcom/example/mysecondapp/MainActivity;.openFile:(Ljava/lang/String;)I
D/AndroidRuntime(  570): Shutting down VM
W/dalvikvm(  570): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a13300)
E/AndroidRuntime(  570): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(  570): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native method not found:  com.example.mysecondapp.MainActivity.openFile:(Ljava/lang/String;)I
E/AndroidRuntime(  570):    at com.example.mysecondapp.MainActivity.openFile(Native  Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(  570):    at   com.example.mysecondapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:31)
E/AndroidRuntime(  570):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
E/AndroidRuntime(  570):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
E/AndroidRuntime(  570):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
E/AndroidRuntime(  570):    at    android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
E/AndroidRuntime(  570):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
E/AndroidRuntime(  570):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
E/AndroidRuntime(  570):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime(  570):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
E/AndroidRuntime(  570):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
E/AndroidRuntime(  570):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(  570):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
E/AndroidRuntime(  570):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
E/AndroidRuntime(  570):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
E/AndroidRuntime(  570):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
W/ActivityManager(  146):   Force finishing activity com.example.mysecondapp/.MainActivity
```

As I could see that native implementation for the openFile() method was not found but the same xyz.so lib worked pretty neat with the original sample app from the third party. I am pretty much a starter with Android-ndk world.

Java-Android-NDK Ninjas ..any guess on what I might be missing ?
I'll highly appreciate any help here :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As guycole said "No JNI_OnLoad" is just a warning , your problem lies elsewhere .

As you mentioned you successfully compiled your "so" file , the problem may lie in your function signatures inside your c/C ++ code  it should be something like this

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_com_your_package_class_method(JNIEnv *d, jobject e, jstring f)
{
//some action

}
```

The function signatures comes from the header file which is generated using  javah tool.You need to generate header file and use the function signature with your package name. For different package and class names the header file and corresponding function signature will change .

```
worked pretty neat with the original sample app from the third party
```

This might be the reason its running on the sample app and not on your app.

refer: https://thenewcircle.com/s/post/49/using_ndk_to_call_c_code_from_android_apps

Comment: right ! the package name could be the reason ! Let me try it out with proper packaging . Will get back to you then, thanks !

Comment: I build .so with new package structure which is my own but now I am getting Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY] error while installing the apk on device in-spite of the fact that xyz.so is present under Project_folder/libs/arm_folder . Any idea what could be behind this ?

Comment: paste your make file and also try to run the example given in the link , you will get some clarity .

Comment: It should be in **Project_folder/libs/armrabi**. You can also open the **.apk** file with WinRAR or other unzip tool, and see what **.so** files it contains.

Comment: I goofed up my AndroidManifest file and hence the error! things are working fine now . Thanks all :)

Answer (score 6):

The "No JNI_OnLoad" message is just a warning.  JNI_OnLoad is an optional initialization hook.

I guess your problem is inside the openFile() method.  Try commenting out the call from Java and see how far you get.

I have a blog post about JNI and some sample code at http://guycole.blogspot.com/2012/03/yet-another-android-ndk-blog-posting.html - perhaps you will find it useful.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks guycole ! you article is pretty comprehensive indeed.

Comment: Exactly. Your blog post is well-done, as well. Nice touch providing source code for JNI callbacks into Java.

Answer (score 2):

It also comes with this log

> ??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/(): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load ***: findLibrary returned null

right??

I think it's the problem of android.mk files. 
1:try to swith to armabi v7. 
2:load funciton  will call open(). check permission of the so.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the previous answers, No JNI_OnLoad is only a warning.

I had got similar problem, I figured the problem is because of file operations.

My app was not having external storage write permission.After adding the below code in
manifest it was working fine